# FlatList only visible if there is at least 2 items

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

In my Expo app I have created a flatlist that takes info from symbols
The value of symbols is just hard coded as below

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            symbols: [{"symbol": "1816ABC","Name": "Some data","icon": "md-star-outline"}],
        }
    }
```

Here is my render function

```
render() {
        if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
            return <Expo.AppLoading />;
          }
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <View style={{paddingVertical: padding.med,alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>
                        ALERTS
                    </Text>
                </View>

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.symbols}
                    extraData={this.state.symbols}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.symbol}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderListSeparator}
                    renderItem={this.renderListItem}
                    onRefresh={() => this.onPullToRefresh()}
                    refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

When symbols only has 1 item, the list does not render and the screen is blank, just the word `ALERTS` appears

When I hard code in a few more items to the `symbols` list, it displays all of the items no problem.

Not sure if this is a problem with my code or the FlatList component

EDIT

```
renderListItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.onPressListItem(index)}
            >
                <MyListItem
                    item={item}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
```

EDIT 2

Live code avaliable here
https://snack.expo.io/@zoonosis/ranting-pudding

Comment: would you share `renderListItem ` ?

Comment: sure, have edited my question

Comment: Can you recreate your error in snack.expo.io?

Comment: Sure, link to snack added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to this problem provided by breadboxio on the expo forums

"So I took a look at your code, and your item is being rendered, just with no width so you can’t see it. By adding width: dimensions.fullWidth to your top level View on the MyListItem, it fixes this issue."

"your separator item has a width on it. for one item, there is no separator item rendered, but for more than one, there is. So once a separator item was rendered, it would stretch the flatlist to the width of that separator item."

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {    console.log(this.state.symbols)
        return (
           <FlatList
                    data={this.state.symbols}
                    extraData={this.state.symbols}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.symbol}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderListSeparator}
                    renderItem={(value,index)=>{
                      return(
                        console.log(value.item.symbol,'hel')
                      )
                    }}

                />

        );
    }
```

Comment: the `console.log(this.state.symbols)` line prints the array to the screen

Comment: the `console.log(value.item.symbol,'hel')` line prints the symbol value plus hel

Comment: you can say that symbols only has 1 item, the list does not render and the screen is blank so i appears single value

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: you say that when you have one symbol you did not render  value of symbol on screen and screen is blank

Comment: Yes I know that. I want to know why it doesn't render anything when there is only 1 item in the list.

Comment: there is above code i sent , that render 1 item of symbol in the list and screen cannot empty

Comment: the above code you sent doesnt render anything, it only displays things in the console

Comment: renderItem={(value,index)=>{
                      return(
                      
                      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',marginTop:140}}>
                        <Text>{value.item.symbol}</Text>
                        </View>
                      )
                    }}

Comment: Your code produces an error. Text strings must be within a <Text> component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191436/discussion-between-lovepreet-singh-and-zoonosis).

Comment: The code can be found here https://snack.expo.io/@zoonosis/ranting-pudding